# Sub-queries in a while loop: what is fastest?

Tags: php

I have to check a parameter in a while loop by counting the number of lines in a table. Right now I am doing it this way but it seems very inefficient

```
while ($stmt->fetch()) {
            $stmt3 = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT id_roster)
            FROM dispo
            WHERE id_member = ?");
            $stmt3->bind_param('i', $id_alerte);  
            $stmt3->execute(); 
            $stmt3->store_result();
            $stmt3->bind_result($number_dispo);
            $stmt3->fetch();
           echo $number_dispo;
      }
```

Any idea how I can make it faster (without repeating the query in each loop iteration?

Comment: Use COUNT together with GROUP BY. (thus running a single query)

Comment: @SergiuParaschiv thanks for the answer. I have to admit I am not very sure to understand your comment. Could you give me more details?

Comment: You could loop over $stmt and then construct your second query using SQL with `member_id IN (X, X, X, X, X)` but the better way is to combine the 2 queries so that you don't need to do any additional queries. Your first like `$stmt->fetch()` would include the information already. You need to give us the full code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to combine the outer query `$stmt` with the inner query `$stmt3`. You've not provided the code for the outer query so i've tried to demonstrate it generally:

```
SELECT ot.*, rc.id_roster_count
FROM other_table ot
LEFT JOIN 
(
    SELECT id_member, COUNT(DISTINCT id_roster) AS id_roster_count
    FROM dispo GROUP BY id_member
)
AS rc ON ot.id_member = rc.id_member
WHERE ot.other_value > 5
```

It may be possible to further optimize this. It depends on your other query and table structure.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. I know you gave me the right solution but I cannot implement it. I put it in another question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28094613/merging-two-querris-with-the-same-binded-parameter

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT 
  id_member, COUNT(DISTINCT dispo.id_roster)
FROM 
  test.dispo
GROUP BY id_member;
```

For this data:

```
id_roster;id_member
1;1
1;1
2;1
3;2
4;2
5;2
6;3
```

produces a list of all `id_member`s together with associated distinct count of `id_roster` for each one:

```
id_member;count
1;2
2;3
3;1
```

You could further limit this query to only certain `id_member`s
by adding a

```
WHERE id_member IN (1,2)
```

clause before the `GROUP BY`.

Comment: thanks a lot for the answer and efforts answering me. I can see your solution should be working but I cannot make it work. Thanks anyways.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by simply extracting all the data in a single query and use group by to format the data and then use the loop to do the desired option.