# Merging two queries with the same binded parameter

Tags: php, mysql

I have a first SQL query getting a table with id_member as parameter

```
    $stmt = $mysqli -> prepare("SELECT  a.id_alerte,
                    a.nom_alerte,
                    ar.id_roster,
                    r.nom_roster,
                FROM alerte a,
                    alerte_par_roster ar,
                    roster_par_membre rm
                INNER JOIN roster r
                    ON r.id_roster = rm.id_roster   
                WHERE rm.id_roster = ar.id_roster 
                    AND ar.id_alerte = a.id_alerte
                    AND rm.id_membre = ?");
            $stmt->bind_param('i', $id_membre);
```

I need to insert a second query counting the number of lines in another table.

The second query is:

```
"SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT id_roster)
                        FROM disponibilites_par_member_alertes
                        WHERE id_member = ?
                        AND id_alerte = ?"
```

As you can notice `id_member` is the identical in both queries but `id_alerte` (used as a parameter of the second query is a result of a first query).
I hope I am clear.
Any idea will be very welcome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't fully understand what your queries are intended to do. It would help to have clear information on the table structure and what each of the fields represents. I've tried to make a guess based on the table names but can't be certain it's correct.

The first thing I did was just to transform your WHERE condition such that each of the tables are joined explicitly. This is just for readability.

```
SELECT 
  a.id_alerte,
  a.nom_alerte,
  ar.id_roster,
  r.nom_roster
FROM alerte a
INNER JOIN alerte_par_roster ar
  ON ar.id_alerte = a.id_alerte
INNER JOIN roster_par_membre rm
  ON rm.id_roster = ar.id_roster 
INNER JOIN roster r
  ON r.id_roster = rm.id_roster
WHERE 
  rm.id_membre = ?
```

Now we combine with the other query:

```
SELECT 
  a.id_alerte,
  a.nom_alerte,
  ar.id_roster,
  r.nom_roster,
  rc.id_roster_count
FROM alerte a
INNER JOIN alerte_par_roster ar
  ON ar.id_alerte = a.id_alerte
INNER JOIN roster_par_membre rm
  ON rm.id_roster = ar.id_roster 
INNER JOIN roster r
  ON r.id_roster = rm.id_roster
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT id_membre, id_alerte, COUNT(DISTINCT id_roster) AS id_roster_count
  FROM disponibilites_par_member_alertes
  GROUP BY id_membre, id_alerte
) AS rc 
  ON rc.id_membre = rm.id_membre
  AND rc.id_alerte = ar.id_alerte
WHERE 
  rm.id_membre = ?
```

With my own generated data I get results like this:

[image: query result]

If this is not enough to solve the problem you will need to provide more details about the tables and the design.